# Hibernate: unidirectional, remove many-to-many association

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

this is my scenario,

i have **SubForum** class, that holds set of moderators, each entity int that set is **User** class.

this is the mapping of the **SubForum**

```
<class name="server.Subforum">
    <id name="id" type="int">
        <column name="subforum_id"></column>
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <properties name="unique_subforum" unique="true">
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="forumId" type="int" access="field">
            <column name="forum_id"></column>
        </property>
    </properties>
    <set name="moderators" table="subforums_moderators"
        lazy="false" fetch="select" >
        <key>
            <column name="SUBFORUM_ID" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many column="user_id" class="server.User" />
    </set>
</class>
```

this is the **User** mapping:

```
<class name="server.User">
    <id name="id" type="int" access="field">
        <column name="user_id"></column>
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="username" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="USERNAME" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="password" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="PASSWORD" />
    </property>
    <property name="registrationDate" type="java.util.Date">
    </property>
</class>
```

that mapping generated the tables as expected, the subforums, users, subforums_moderators, with all the right configuration.

The problem is that when i try to delete "moderator" from the sub_forum`s set, this action is not reflected in DB.
(when i am adding new moderator to the same list, there is association in the **subforums_moderators** as expected).

when i remove the whole sub-forum, all the association in the **subforums_moderators** removed also.

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: OK, it WORKED!
thank you.

there is some thing strange, now when i add user, (its adds to the DB), delete him (it deletes in the DB), and add the same one again, there is no association to him...

and also, when i delete the entire subforum, it tries to delete the user it self, but i don't want it...i want only to delete the association.

Comment: >and add the same one again, there is no association to him. Sorry this is not clear. Ask this one more time.

Comment: and add the same user once again, there is no association to him in the DB.

Comment: Your original mapping files should work.  Can you post the code snippet where you delete the moderator from the set, and save to the Session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<set name="moderators" table="subforums_moderators"
        lazy="false" fetch="select" >`
to this :

```
 <set name="moderators" table="subforums_moderators"
        lazy="false" cascade="delete" fetch="select" >
```

Comment: now, when i delete the entire sub forum, its tries to delete the User from the users table, and i wanna only delete the association.

Comment: What do you mean by delete the association ? The association is the user Id, right ? And the user Id is tied to a user. So if you delete the association, with cascading it will delete the user also. What are you exactly trying to do ?

Comment: like i said before, there are 3 tables, subforums, users, subforums_moderators. the last one the the many to many association table. it keeps subforum_id, user_id, i wanna only remove the user from being moderator, not remove the user from the system. so the cascade options tries to remove the user itself not only the association.

Comment: some one has any solution to delete only the association in the subforums_moderators table?
its not remove the association if i removes the user object from the moderators list that exists in the Subforum Object.

Comment: If you dont vote for something which helped you in the first place, how do you expect people to help you out mate ?

Comment: I think CaTz hasn't voted yet because he hasn't quite got an answer to the problem.  :)

Comment: you right, all the suggestions here was to delete on of the ends, the user or the sub-forum, what iam looking for is to delete the connection between them.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your original mapping files are fine.  You do not want `cascade="delete"` - a User should exist in the DB independently of whether they are the moderator for a particular forum.
2. ***now when i add user, (its adds to the DB), delete him (it deletes in the DB), and add the same one again, there is no association to him**

   You need to re-add the same user, and then you need to reassociate that user with a subforum: `subforum.addModerator(user)`  or `subforum.getModerators().add(user)`.

   In fact, users, subforums and moderator associations should be created, updated and deleted independently.  Typical workflow:

   ```
        after  app functionality         DB operation   DB tables  
   A.   -      add user(s)               Insert         USERS
   B.   A.     add subforum with 
               starting moderator(s) 
               (link(s) to user(s))      Insert         SUBFORUMS, SUBFORUMS_MODERATORS 
   C.   B.     add moderator(s) to a 
               subforum                  Insert         SUBFORUMS_MODERATORS
   D.   B.     remove moderator(s)
               from a subforum           Delete         SUBFORUMS_MODERATORS
   E.   B.     remove a subforum         Delete         SUBFORUMS_MODERATORS, SUBFORUMS 
   F.   A.     semove a user that is 
               not a moderator of any 
               subforum                  Delete         USERS
   ```
3. ***also, when i delete the entire subforum, it tries to delete the user it self, but i don't want it...i want only to delete the association***

   That's a cascaded delete from subforum to user.  Don't use cascaded delete here.  Instead, remove the association via `subforum.getModerators().remove(user)` and then delete the subforum.  You are responsible for manually coding data changes to associations and entities (two places).  If you change just one of these, then hibernate doesn't automatically populate/clear the other.

Answer (score 0):

that is because you set the sub forum_id in user to not null. so you can't delete the sub forum that is used in user.
so you must change your mapping and recreate your table, or just change the sub forum manually in your database so the user.subforum_id can be nullable.
and then you can change user.subforumId to null where user.subforumId = deletedSubforumId and then delete the subforum

Comment: i don`t want to delete the sub-forum, or the user itself. all i need is to remove the association, so the specific user will not be an moderator of the given sub-forum, that is all.

Comment: then cant you just use 3 table if you confuse about that many to many relationship behaviour? delete that set and make 1 table instead with sub forum_id and `< column="user_id" type="int" />` instead of using object(user). and manage that 3rd table manually